# What's a great way to see what parachain auctions are happening right now?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, crowdloan, auctions

What's a great way to see what parachain auctions are happening at the moment for kusama and polkadot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Kusama

  - Crowdloans

    - [Polkadot.js Apps - Kusama](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains/crowdloan)
    - [Subscan - Kusama](https://kusama.subscan.io/crowdloan)
    - [CoinMarketCap - Kusama](https://coinmarketcap.com/polkadot-parachains/kusama/crowdload/)
  - Auctions

    - [Polkadot.js Apps - Kusama](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains/auctions)
    - [Subscan - Kusama](https://kusama.subscan.io/auction)
    - [CoinMarketCap - Kusama](https://coinmarketcap.com/polkadot-parachains/kusama/auction/)
  - Both Crowdloans & Auctions

    - [DotMarketCap - Kusama](https://dotmarketcap.com/auction)
    - [Parallel Finance - Kusama](https://crowdloan.parallel.fi/#/auction/kusama)
    - [Parachains.info - Kusama](https://parachains.info/auctions/kusama)
- Polkadot

  - Crowdloans

    - [Polkadot.js Apps - Polkadot](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/parachains/crowdloan)
    - [Subscan - Polkadot](https://polkadot.subscan.io/crowdloan)
    - [CoinMarketCap - Polkadot](https://coinmarketcap.com/polkadot-parachains/polkadot/crowdload/)
  - Auctions

    - [Polkadot.js Apps - Polkadot](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/parachains/auctions)
    - [Subscan - Polkadot](https://polkadot.subscan.io/auction)
    - [CoinMarketCap - Polkadot](https://coinmarketcap.com/polkadot-parachains/polkadot/auction/)
  - Both Crowdloans & Auctions

    - [DotMarketCap - Polkadot](https://dotmarketcap.com/auction/polkadot)
    - [Parallel Finance - Polkadot](https://crowdloan.parallel.fi/#/auction/polkadot)
    - [Parachains.info - Polkadot](https://parachains.info/auctions/polkadot)
- Both Kusama & Polkadot

  - Crowdloans

    - [Fearless Wallet](https://fearlesswallet.io)
    - [Nova Wallet](https://novawallet.io/)
    - [Subsocial Sub.ID](https://sub.id)

Comment: I second parachains.info

Comment: Have been using parachains.info myself but great to see there are so many others to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from looking directly on the polkadot.js site, I like to use

- parachains.info
- https://dotmarketcap.com/

Comment: Nice. Hadn't found dotmarketcap.